# Is it possible to make a Window unselectable when using "ALT Tab" shortkey?

Tags: window-manager, 19.04, application-switcher

A situation image:[image: screenshot]

Here I don't want to switch/use a Chrome Window which is below the VS Code. Because it gets refreshed automatically. I don't need to touch it.

xdg-session type: X11
GNOME: 3.32.1
OS: Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: For example, KWin has this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULHWC.png

Comment: @DKBose how do I know that? (newbie). I think its Wayland. The default one which comes with Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @DKBose the question is now updated.

Comment: @DKBose Apparently wmctrl was already installed. "wmctrl -m" output is "Name: GNOME Shell, Class: N/A, PID: N/A, Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF".

Comment: @DKBose what does that mean? Is it not possible?

Comment: It just means that I don't know. Which is to say that someone, maybe in a different time-zone, may know the solution.